# django-tailwindcss integration image not displayed

Tags: django, image, templates, tailwind-css

I already have a Django project with template file index.html but my image is not displaying I try everything including {% load static %} but still it is not working may be because i used {% load tailwind_tags %} and {% tailwind_css %} and i also created file as mentioned in Django official website for static file but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Tailwind CSS correctly?

I was facing the same issue. Here's what I did:

1. Installed the `django-tailwind` package.
2. Created a static folder at root of the project and then configured the `settings.py` file.
3. Loaded the `{% load static tailwind_tags %} {% load static %}` to the template. After that,  the image path in the template will be: `<div class="py-1"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.svg' %}" alt=""></div>`.
4. I also have another open terminal running `python manage.py tailwind start`.